# HTML attributes not working in in popover

Tags: html, css

```
....
....
Some data
<span popover-placement="top" popover="content1, content2" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
  <span class="fas fa-info-circle" style="font-size: 12px;"></span>
</span>
....
```

I want to change the content1 and content2 into two lines using `<br>`
I tried `data-html="true"`, it doesn't work, I do believe, that's because it only works in the case like this -> `data-toggle="popover" data-content="content1 <br> content2"`

so is there any way to add 
 in the first method? please make your suggestions and help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap's popovers, you are missing an element property to make the HTML popover work. Add this property `data-html="true"` to your span element with the tooltip and if it still doesn't render properly, run this on DOM ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
})
```